# How to Run Cron Task Once with Node-Schedule

Tags: node.js, date, server, cron, node-schedule

I used [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) to schedule a task executed only once for all at particular time. The doc shows that for me:

> Date-based Scheduling: Say you very specifically want a function to
> execute at 5:30am on December 21, 2012. Remember - in JavaScript - 0 -
> January, 11 - December.
>
> ```
> const schedule = require('node-schedule');
> const date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);
>
> const job = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
>   console.log('The world is going to end today.');
> });
> ```

But this code runs the task every minute, I just want it to run the task only once at the particular time specified as here:

```
const date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);
```

The date here is a default. I changed it for future date in my code as below:

```
const now = new Date().getTime();
const seconds = 180;
const parsedDate = new Date(Date.parse(now));
const date = new Date(parsedDate.getTime() + (1000 * seconds));
schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(data) {
    console.log("Job ran @", new Date().toString());
});
```

Here I just want to cron a job after 180 seconds (3 minute) from current date. But console result shows that console log is written every minutes after deploy:

```
>  Job ran @ Tue Mar 16 2021 08:56:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
>  Job ran @ Tue Mar 16 2021 08:57:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
>  Job ran @ Tue Mar 16 2021 08:58:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
>  Job ran @ Tue Mar 16 2021 08:59:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get over this issue by adding time zone into my code. I use an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57842203/15406338) from another post. The function here comes with adding time zone feature to Date function in easy way.

> This should solve your problem, please feel free to offer fixes. This
> method will account also for daylight saving time for the given date.
>
> ```
>   Date dateWithTimeZone = (timeZone, year, month, day, hour, minute, second) => {
>   let date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second));
>
>   let utcDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "UTC" }));
>   let tzDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: timeZone }));
>   let offset = utcDate.getTime() - tzDate.getTime();
>
>   date.setTime( date.getTime() + offset );
>
>   return date;
> };
> ```

And then my code looks like that:

```
schedule.scheduleJob(dateWithTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul",
      req.body.year, req.body.month, req.body.day, req.body.hour,
      req.body.minute, req.body.second), function(data) {
    console.log("Job ran @", new Date().toString());
});
```

And finally it works fine for me. I can schedule job executed only once at the time I prefer in my time zone.

Thanks for your attention. Regarding...

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to schedule a cron job.

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const moment = require('moment');

const rule = scheduled.RecurrenceRule();

let time = '2021-07-30 14:20:00';
rule.tz = 'Asia/Kolkata';
rule.year = moment(time).year();
rule.month = moment(time).month();
rule.date = moment(time).date();
rule.hour = moment(time).hours();
rule.minute = moment(time).minutes();
rule.second = moment(time).seconds();
schedule.scheduleJob(rule, async function () {
     console.log("Scheduled")
});
```

Comment: Where is 'scheduled' variable declared?